# How do I convert a multi-line string of numbers into a 2d array of integers?

Tags: python

I'm doing a Project Euler problem (https://projecteuler.net/problem=18) and want to paste in the triangle as a multi-line string and convert it into a 2d array of integers. I assume you use list comprehension with string splitting and the int() function but everything I try either turns it into a 1d array or doesn't compile.

Comment: You read line by line and map `string.split()` to int and append to an list

Answer (score 2):

A nested list comprehension will work. First, split on `'\n'`, then split on `' '`, then convert each of those numbers to an integer.

```
triangle = """75
95 64
17 47 82
18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
19 01 23 75 03 34
88 02 77 73 07 63 67
99 65 04 28 06 16 70 92
41 41 26 56 83 40 80 70 33
41 48 72 33 47 32 37 16 94 29
53 71 44 65 25 43 91 52 97 51 14
70 11 33 28 77 73 17 78 39 68 17 57
91 71 52 38 17 14 91 43 58 50 27 29 48
63 66 04 68 89 53 67 30 73 16 69 87 40 31
04 62 98 27 23 09 70 98 73 93 38 53 60 04 23"""

triangle_lst = [[int(num) for num in row.split(' ')] for row in triangle.split('\n')]
```